# get previous selected dropdown item

Tags: jquery, button, drop-down-menu

i have the following code where i have a dropdown list (with class="**addToList**" and followed by a button (Class="**addtoButton**"):

When i click on the button, i want to grab the current selected value and text from the previous dropdown list.

```
$(".addToPortalButton").live('click', function (e) {

// grab the previous dropdown list value and text here.

});
```

what is the easiest way to doing this using jquery.

Here is the html:

```
<select class="addToList" id="Teams" name="Teams">
     <option></option>
    <option value="49">Team 1</option>
    <option value="22">Team 2</option>
</select>
<input type='button' class="addToButton" value='Add to' />

<select class="addToList" id="Teams" name="Teams">
     <option></option>
    <option value="49">Team 1</option>
    <option value="22">Team 2</option>
</select>
<input type='button' class="addToButton" value='Add to' />

<select class="addToList" id="Teams" name="Teams">
     <option></option>
    <option value="49">Team 1</option>
    <option value="22">Team 2</option>
</select>
<input type='button' class="addToButton" value='Add to' />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) or [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) to get the `<select>` before like this:

*Edit:* for newer versions of jQuery where `.live()` has been deprecated, the new [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) syntax is:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addToButton', function (e) {
  var sel = $(this).prevAll('.addToList:first'),
      val = sel.val(),
      text = sel.find(':selected').text();    
});
```

*Older version:*

```
$(".addToButton").live('click', function (e) {
  var sel = $(this).prevAll(".addToList:first"),
      val = sel.val(),
      text = sel.find(':selected').text();    
});
```

Comment: @Nick Craver - i want to leverage the class name as what if i stick something after the dropdown and before the button in the future.  is there a more future-proof solution

Comment: @ooo - updated with a slightly more future-proof way to do this, searching all previous siblings until `.addToList` is found

Comment: @Nick Craver - at those supposed to be commas or semicolons at the end of the first and second lines ??

Comment: @ooo - commas, using a single `var`, you could do semicolons, and a `var` on each line as well.

Comment: @Nick Craver - ah .. thanks, didn't realize this (i apologize for by being naive and questioning your correctness :) )

Comment: @ooo - there are no stupid questions!, well there *are*, but that wasn't one :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following code:

```
$(".addToButton").on('click', function (e) {

    var $el = $(this).prev().find('option:selected');

});
```

You can then use `$el.val()` and `$el.text()` to get the value and text respectively.